# NETWORKDAYS.INTL in Java

Tags: java

Excel has a function named NETWORKDAYS.INTL. It receives a start date, an end date, a "type" of weekend and a list of holidays and calculates the number of working days between the two dates. The weekend flag is important because I can consider saturday as a working day. More info here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/networkdays-intl-function-HA010354379.aspx

Is there something like NETWORKDAYS.INTL in Java? Using ObjectLab Kit, Joda and Jollyday I can keep my national holidays and check if the day is saturday, sunday or holiday, but to calculate like the function above I need to iterate over each day and check if valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found nothing so I just code my own method. In my application all dates are saved as timestamp.

```
public boolean isHoliday(long date) {
    return holidaysCalendar.isHoliday(new LocalDate(date));
}

public boolean isSaturday(long date) {
    return (new LocalDate(date).dayOfWeek().get() == 7);
}

public boolean isSunday(long date) {
    return (new LocalDate(date).dayOfWeek().get() == 1);
}

public boolean isValid(long date, boolean saturday, boolean sunday) {
    boolean valid = true;
    if (isHoliday(date)) {
        valid = false;
    } else {
        if (!saturday && isSaturday(date)) {
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!sunday && isSunday(date)) {
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}

public long addDays(long date, int days) {
    return new LocalDate(date).plusDays(days).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()
            .getMillis();
}

public int validDaysBetweenDates(long date1, long date2,
        boolean saturday, boolean sunday) {
    date1 = addDias(date1, 1);
    int cont = 0;
    for (long dateTmp = date1; dataTmp <= date2; dataTmp = addDays(dataTmp, 1)) {
        if (isValid(dataTmp, saturday, sunday))
            cont++;
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this code by using `DayOfWeek` enum rather than mere integers. `myLocalDate.getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )`